# (Java/Regex) How can I find "http://" excepting "src="http://"

Tags: java, regex

I have problem with regex on Java, right now.

I have string like:

```
img border=\"0\" src=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com http://nbsp;https://&lt
```

and wanna make a regex that find only two "http://" excepting "src=\"http://" to replace the "http://" to something else.

```
String input = "border=\"0\" src=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com http://";
String regexStr = "(?!src=\"http://).*$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.matches())
  System.out.println("String " + input + " has the word src=\"http:// in it ");
else
  System.out.println("String " + input + " hasn't the word src=\"http:// in it ");
```

I'm searching related with this, but didn't find perfect answer yet.

Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are parsing some XML you can use other technologies to do this like XSLT for example or any XML parser! Regex are not the best option here

Comment: Are http:// always located at the end of the string?

Comment: For your example is enough to search for `" http://"`

Comment: @Allan no, the "http://" could be anywhere

Comment: @montonero good point. edited.

Comment: Does my solution work as expected?

Comment: @Allan yes, it is and helped me a lot! Thanks for nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<!src=")http://(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

One of the numerous regex that will match URLs as defined in 
[What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

INPUT:

```
border="0" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com 
123 http://abc123.com asg
123 http://uvw-avc132.be abc
```

MATCHES:

```
http://abc123.com 
http://uvw-avc132.be
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/SOyEtd/2

If you want to get only the `http://`, then use only:

```
(?<!src=")http://
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/SOyEtd/4

Embedded in Java:

```
    String input = "border=\"0\" src=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com http://";
    String output=input.replaceAll("(?<!src=\")http://","something else");
    System.out.println(output);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
border="0" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com something else
```

Comment: No need to escape the forward slashes - they're not special in Java regular expressions.  And could you maybe explain what that first, very long regular expression is doing?  It's not very obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detail response.it works well. Appreciate it !

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression you want is

```
(?<!src=")http://
```

The part in the parentheses is a "negative lookbehind".  It means *not preceded by `src="`*.

Of course, when you write this in a Java String literal, it will have to be

```
"(?<!src=\")http://"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, it works well. Appreciate it !